# My Wordpress Custom Plugin unexpectedly change header information and give Error

Tags: php, wordpress

I develop custom plugin for wordpress.
but i didn't understand why it is give me header error in my live server.
but not in my WAMPP Server.

here is the message error

`Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/villapor/public_html/wp-content/plugins/villa-management/includes/inc.villaportal.php:596) in /home/villapor/public_html/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 897`

Here is the index plugin file, i put it in ideone.com because the code is to long
http://ideone.com/4TS4B

and this is the content of `inc.villaportal.php` as mentioned in the error message above
http://ideone.com/FJR4K

please inform me if you need another content of file to view to help me resolve this :)

thank you in advance,
GusDe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry this maybe look bit funny, but i found the solution after read at wordpress doc
http://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_Troubleshooting
at section `How do I solve the Headers already sent warning problem?`

there is extra space at the of my file `inc.villaportal.php`. the space located at the end of my file `?>`

---

Thank you for your time